# Win 7 -- mice only work in safe mode -- what does it mean?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse, boot-camp

My  Windows 7 system on Mac via Boot Camp isn't seeing *any* mice.

Mice were working fine up until yesterday, then suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason.

Move the mouse around, cursor stays in place.

I'm seeing this with my Razer "Naga" gaming mouse and also with a plain vanilla Microsoft USB mouse.

I tried the mice into a different machines and they worked.

I rebooted Windows 7 into safe mode.

In safe mode, the mice both work.

(BTW I updated the "Naga" driver from Razer's website, of course. I also updated the .Net framework as recommended by Razor support.)

## UPDATE

Here pics to show what I'm seeing...

## Device manager in normal mode

### (Mice are not working)

[image]

## Device manager in safe mode

### (Mice ARE working)

[image]

What do I need to install or uninstall and from where to get these fine mice to work in normal mode?

Comment: Did you install some mouse driver, maybe? Safe mode loads only the Windows' default drivers. Anyway, try to remove mouse drivers in device manager and reboot, hope you can navigate to shutdown using your keyboard then :)

Comment: I'd try to remove ALL of them drivers for mice while in safe mode and then reboot to Windows normally using keyboard

Comment: What do you have under `Human Interface Devices`, if all is enabled there, you may try to disable and re-enable again?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reply. If safe mode boots the machine with Win basic drivers & I remove them, won't that mean I'm removing my basic Windows drivers & messing up the system? (Sorry if that's a naive question -- I'm not very familiar with Windows.)

Comment: I don't think removing the drivers from device manager actually deletes the driver files from the computer; it just disassociates the files from the particular device, so next time you plug in the device, it should detect it as a new device and load the appropriate drivers automatically